# Change not showing in _Layout.cshtml; is compile needed

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a ASP.Net MVC project. in that project .cs files are not available. I have made some changes in Views\Shared_Layout.cshtml  file. but my changes are not showing. my question is "is each time compile of entire project necessary?"

I have no code files; only have FTP and .cshtml files showing. How can I make changes in _Layout.cshtml file? so my change will show?

Comment: If you made no changes to you backend code, there is no need to recompiling any HTML views. You can just while app is running make any changes to views and by reloading page the changes will be shown

Answer (score 0):

You just have to save your _Layout page and upload it on FTP under Shared folder.
Changes will reflect on server.
In case you are using localhost, just save the file and changes will reflect as soon as you do.
You can also try hard reloading the page to clear cache and cookies.
i.e "Ctrl + Shift + R" for google chrome.